# Failed attempt to make LM3404 drive a 10W white led

Tags: led, buck, led-driver

I'm attempting to drive a 10W white led (ebay type, 8-11V, 1A) with a LM3404. I've approximated their reference circuit:

[image]

I've used a 33uH (1.6A) inductor as L1 and a schottky diode (SS24, 2A 40V) as D1. For the boostrapping capacitor Cb, a 10nf ceramic did the trick. I didn't used any Rsns for the reason explained below. Vin was set to 12V. The decoupling capacitor Cin was the typical electrolytic 100uF.

My problem is that the IF measured through the LED is a mere 20mA, and I'm baffled to why that is so. Varying the Rsns only makes the current go lower. Doubling the inductor from 33uH to 66uH makes absolutely no difference. I attempted Vin from 8v to 25v. Going from 12v to 25v did absolutely nothing. **But going down to around 8.8v did made the led get a little brighter.**

What am I missing?

Addenda:

I replicated the circuit as follows; with these settings, the voltage across the led is 5.2V and (obviously) it doesn't lit. The PWM is being controlled by an ESP8266 (I confirmed it is working with a regular led).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKsWi4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Fake ebay LED??

Comment: Tried a lot of leds; all the same. They work with regular drivers.

Comment: Try setting Vin a bit higher, maybe? Check the sense voltage with a VOM to see if the controller is in regulation. And if you have an oscilloscope, probe the switch node to see what the duty cycle is. If the duty cycle is 100%, or whatever the max is for this chip, that could indicate that Vin needs to be higher.

Comment: What is the input voltage Vin? This is a buck converter and Vin needs to be at least 1V higher than the LED forward voltage.

Comment: He says Vin is 12V. Which seems a bit marginal given that the LED has a voltage drop of supposedly 11V (and is of "ebay type" so non-existent datasheet).

Comment: What value are you using for Ron? And what switching frequency did you design for?

Comment: i tried all values up to 25v, and the led doesn't even get slightly brighter

Comment: @HugoSFerreira, Please post a complete schematic showing exactly how you connected everything, and also a photograph of the actual circuit and test setup. It is not likely that there is an error in the reference schematic or PCB layout, so the problem must be in your schematic or layout. We need to see it to have any chance of finding it. Please advise if you have access to oscilloscopes, volt meters, etc.

Comment: The fact that you omitted Rsns is a huge red flag to me. It is required for the device to operate. Without it, I can think of two possibilities: First maybe you have high resistance between CS and GND due to long skinny wires or some such. Second, maybe the the device is going into its current limit mode, which would cause the LED to not really turn on properly. This is why we need the schematic and picture.

Comment: I'll replicate the circuit with all the resistors (Ron and Rsns) and take a picture. I don't have access to an oscilloscope right now; only a multimeter and a USB logic analyser (Saleae Logic Pro 8)...

Comment: @mkeith there you go; can I provide you any more info?

Comment: Just a quick comment. The controller operates by regulating Vsense to 0.2V. This means that with Rsense = 10 Ohms, you would expect the output current to be 0.2V/10 Ohms = 0.02A (20 mA). If you want the output to be, say, 0.5A, you would want Rsense to be 0.2V/0.5A = 0.4 Ohms. I will look into it in more detail later, but let me know if that helps.

Comment: It's worth trying (and it does make sense). I'll buy something smaller than 10 Ohms tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, I've found an online calculator: http://embed.plnkr.co/sVZE1gBt6sMM0XU7ELE2/preview; the values seem highly sensible...

Comment: If you have more than one 10ohm-resistor you can parallel them :-)

Comment: Are you sure your capacitors are made of X7R ceramic? The datasheet demands this material (for Cb and Cf). It's possible yours are made of Y5V, which has much worse tolerances. Do you even have a Cf? I don't see it.

Comment: There's only one capacitor needed for the BOOT pin, and, afaik, is only used to "bootstrap" the buck circuit, no?

Comment: No, you need to bypass the power supply rail with Cf. Practically always and for any high-enough frequency chip. Place as close as possible to the chip.

Comment: But that's just a decoupling capacitor; do you think that would make any difference besides a little flicker?

Comment: https://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/an13/an1325.pdf for the general idea. Also, the datasheet of your LM3404 doesn't say anywhere it might be optional. It says "The linear regulator filter capacitor CF must always be a 100-nF ceramic capacitor, also with X7R dielectric and a 25-V rating."

Comment: And if that's not enough, it says in a different place in the datasheet "The LM3404 and LM3404HV devices contain an internal linear regulator with a 7-V output, connected between
the VIN and the VCC pins. The VCC pin must be bypassed to the GND pin with a 0.1-µF ceramic capacitor
connected as close as possible to the pins of the IC."

Comment: I'm kind of amazed on how an output pin such as VCC can possibly have anything to do with this... But I'll try.

Comment: By the way, only Co (not Cf) enters in the calculation of the load ripple; see fig. 20 in the datasheet. Your circuit likely has multiple problems, but this (lacking Cf) is surely one of them. Switching regulators are sensitive to layout and seldom work properly on plug-in board.

Comment: Regarding your chosen switching frequency (determined by Ron and Vout), it's about 175kHz. Doable on a breadboard if you're lucky. But I would consider lowering if you can afford it (meaning you'll need a larger inductor). Also mkeith is correct regarding Rsns. To get around 2A out for IL-min, you need to have Rsns of 0.1 ohms for your chosen inductor (33u).

Comment: And also, your inductor needs to be able to handle the 2A+ripple without saturating. At 33uH such a tiny inductor will almost certainly not qualify.

Comment: And one more issue: your Cin is an electrolytic, while the datasheet recommends a low-ESR ceramic (at least X5R, with X7R being recommended). At the 175KHz switching frequency (and assuming 2A output), the value of Cin you've chosen (10uF) is good up to 5% Vin variation (ripple). Alas with the combination of high output current and relatively low switching frequency, the value of Cin is going to be challenge if you follow the datasheet and go for ceramic. The alternative is to have an upsteam power supply with low[er] ripple.

Comment: By the way, I've done a calculation with the component values he has chosen,  and at 12V input, the max output voltage would be 11.35V.